# HDBSCAN cluster caching and persistance

Tags: python, scipy, pickle, dbscan, hdbscan

HDBSCAN has a flag to cache its cluster data as a param like mentioned below:

```
prediction_data :boolean, optional

Whether to generate extra cached data for predicting labels or membership vectors few new unseen points later. If you wish to persist the clustering object for later re-use you probably want to set this to True. (default False)
```

Now I see that at a specifed location, below folder structure is created:

```
>joblib
...>hdbscan
......>hdbscan_
.........>_hdbscan_boruvka_balltree
............>f1bd5f351764560c3532dbe30f273481
...............metadata.json
...............output.pkl
............func_code.py
```

As HDBSCAN docs [suggest](https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#hdbscan.hdbscan_.HDBSCAN), we can use these files (probably the pickle file) as a persistence store and it can be later re-used for finding cluster labels for new data points. But I don't find a way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

I got here when I was searching for caching memory in HDBSCAN. My original search led me to https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/memory_basic_usage.html
where I found the code below:

```
from joblib import Memory
location = './cachedir'
memory = Memory(location, verbose=0)
```

but on using it, I got a

```
DeprecationWarning: The 'cachedir' parameter has been deprecated in version 0.12 and will 
be removed in version 0.14. 
You provided "cachedir='/tmp/joblib'", use "location='/tmp/joblib'" instead.
```

Thus, leading to the updated code for caching memory in HDBSCAN using joblib

```
from joblib import Memory
location='/tmp/joblib'
memory = Memory(location, verbose=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter you want to look at is `memory=`. If you call HDBSCAN a second time with the same `memory=` parameter and only change (say) the `min_cluster_size` explicitly holding the `min_samples` fixed between runs, then it will save you recompute time.

Comment: 1. how do we set the path we want into memory? The documentation talks little about it , if I want to save it under the directory my script is by the name ```results``` for example , if I put ```memory = 'results``` where is this going to be stored?
2. How do we load the model ? There is no info in the documentation, do we use the load() function of joblib?